# How do I expect 'echo -e "? \c"'?

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo, expect

I have been asked to write a script that interacts with another one - but I'm stuck. The script that I interact with echos the following and I need to send a "1" back. But I can't quite get there...

```
echo -e "Select option 1"
echo -e "? \c"
```

So far I have tried - for as far as I remember:

```
expect "?"
send "1" 

expect "? "
send "1"

expect "? \n"
send "1"

expect "? \c"
send "1"
```

It all doesn't seem to work. Can somebody please give me a nudge in the right direction...? :)

P.S.: I assume I'll need to add a `\r` to the `1` once I take the first hurdle...

Comment: Try `expect -ex "? "`

Comment: `?` is a wildcard that matches any character, so yes, you need `-ex`, or `expect "\\?"` or `expect {\?}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `echo -e "? \c"`, the `\c` part is not anything that gets printed out, it's a directive to the `echo` command to not print a newline after the string passed as an argument¹. So in expect, you need to expect the string `"? "` (question mark, space). Since the argument of the `expect` command is a pattern where `?` is a wildcard, you need to interpret the question mark literally:

```
expect -ex "? "
send "1\r"
```

¹  <sub>Some other implementations of `echo`, such as the bash builtin, use the syntax `echo -n "?"` for this.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  Consider using the `read` built in (From [TDLP: Catching User Input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)):

### Read Example

`cat leaptest.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will test if you have given a leap year or not.

echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"

read year

if (( ("$year" % 400) == "0" )) || (( ("$year" % 4 == "0") && ("$year" % 100 !=
"0") )); then
  echo "$year is a leap year."
else
  echo "This is not a leap year."
fi
```

Notice **Line 6**.  The variable year is created on the fly, by BASH to hold the output for the echo statement.

### Testing User Input Example

`cat friends.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a program that keeps your address book up to date.

friends="/var/tmp/michel/friends"

echo "Hello, "$USER".  This script will register you in Michel's friends database."

echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo -n "Enter your gender and press [ENTER]: "
read -n 1 gender
echo

grep -i "$name" "$friends"

if  [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "You are already registered, quitting."
  exit 1
elif [ "$gender" == "m" ]; then
  echo "You are added to Michel's friends list."
  exit 1
else
  echo -n "How old are you? "
  read age
  if [ $age -lt 25 ]; then
    echo -n "Which colour of hair do you have? "
    read colour
    echo "$name $age $colour" >> "$friends" 
    echo "You are added to Michel's friends list.  Thank you so much!"
  else
    echo "You are added to Michel's friends list."
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

In your particular case, you would replace **Line 5** with the list of options from the script, and starting at line 17 modify the if to match the option which you passed as `ANS`.  If the option matches the `if`, execute your script, as in `sh myscript.sh --option ANS`

Comment: The actual script I'm talking to has a READ statement: 
`echo -e "Select option 1"`
`echo -e "? \c"`
`read ANS`

But my script is calling that script and mine then tires to "play" user... Sorry if that was unclear...

Comment: You're forgetting that you can pass ANS to your script as an argument.